# I want it to print the hello_ch variable but I cannot find a way to do so Chinese translation tool

Tags: python

So I want to translate English to another language in this example, *Chinese*.

So I want for you to be able to enter some term and be able to add a prefix to define a variable and prints it's value.

My code:

```
print("Hey there! Welcome to Max's Translation Tool!")
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
lang = input("Howdy " + name + "! What language would you like to translate to:")

hello = "Hello"
hello_ch = str("你好")

if lang == "chinese":
  term = input("Please enter a term to translate:")
  print(str(term + "_ch"))
```

I want it to print the `hello_ch` variable but I can not find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To maintain your logic. I have used `eval` function to help print out the string.

```
print("Hey there! Welcome to Max's Translation Tool!")
name = input('Please enter your name: ')
lang = input("Howdy " + name + "! What language would you like to translate to:")

hello = "Hello"
hello_ch = str("你好")


if lang == "chinese":
  term = input("Please enter a term to translate:")
  print ( eval( term+"_ch"))  ##this prints out  hello_ch
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a `dict`, not a bunch of similarly named variables.

```
words = {"hello": {"chinese": "你好"}}

term = input("Please enter a term to translate")
print(words[term][lang])
```